# How to free DAG-like data structure

Tags: c, free, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the following DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) data structure:

```c
struct dag {
    struct dag **children;  // Array of pointers to DAGs
    int n_children;         // Number of children
};
```

I want this to be a DAG and not just a tree, which means some of the children of a given DAG may be identical.
This raises a problem in the deletion function:

```c
void del(struct dag *d)
{
    if (d != NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < d->n_children; i++) {
            del(d->children[i]);
        }
        free(d->children);
        free(d);
    }
}
```

Indeed, I end up freeing stuff which is already freed, as shown by the example below (which raises a segmentation fault). This code creates two DAGs `a` and `b`; `a` has no children, `b` has two children which are both `a`.

```c
void main()
{
    struct dag *a, *b, **b_children;

    a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
    a->children = NULL;
    a->n_children = 0;

    b_children = malloc(sizeof(a) * 2);
    b_children[0] = a;
    b_children[1] = a;

    b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
    b->children = b_children;
    b->n_children = 2;

    del(b);
}
```

What is flawed in this approach ? Can I write a `del` function that does what I want ?

Comment: Add a reference count member to `dag`. Increment it when adding a dag to a dag's children. Instead of blindly free'ing a dag, decrement its reference count. If its reference count is zero, then free it.

Comment: That's actually pretty clever, thank you !

Comment: @JeffHolt Maybe consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a directed acyclic graph, the nodes may be referenced from multiple parents, which requires extra bookkeeping to handle the life cycle.

There are multiple approaches for this:

- you can add a reference count in each node, increment it for every extra pointer that references the node and decrement it whenever a pointer no longer references the node, in particular when the parent node is to be freed. Reference counting is very tricky to implement correctly and reliably, and is not a complete solution if your graph ever becomes more complex, ie: if there are actual cycles.
- you can maintain a linked list of allocated nodes and free the full list when the tree is freed. This approach allows for arbitrary node cross references but does not allow for freeing individual nodes. You can only free the whole tree at once. You can still delete individual nodes from the tree but they will remain allocated in the list until you free the whole tree. Also note that the overhead is equivalent: an extra pointer instead vs: a single integer is needed for each node.

Depending on the specifics of the problem you are solving with this tree, one approach might be more appropriate than the other.

In both cases, you should use functions to allocate, update and delete the nodes.

Here is a version with reference counts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int total_dag_nodes = 0;  // for debugging

struct dag {
    int refs;
    int n_children;         // Number of children
    struct dag **children;  // Array of pointers to DAGs
};

struct dag *new_dag(int n) {
    struct dag *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;
    total_dag_nodes++;
    s->refs = 1;
    s->n_children = 0;
    s->children = NULL;
    if (n > 0) {
        s->n_children = n;
        s->children = calloc(sizeof(*s->children), n);
    }
    return s;
}

void free_dag(struct dag *s) {
    if (s && --s->refs <= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s->n_children; i++)
            free_dag(s->children[i]);
        free(s);
        total_dag_nodes--;
    }
}

int set_dag_child(struct dag *s, int n, struct dag *child) {
    if (s == NULL || n < 0 || n >= s->n_children) {
        /* invalid argument */
        return -1;
    }
    struct dag *prev = s->children[n];
    s->children[n] = child;
    if (child != NULL)
        child->refs++;
    /* delay freeing the previous node to avoid freeing it
       if it is identical to new one. */
    free_dag(prev);
    return 0;
}

void print_dag(const char *name, struct dag *s) {
    printf("%s: %p", name, (void*)s);
    if (s) {
        printf(" [refs:%d] {", s->refs);
        for (int i = 0; i < s->n_children; i++)
            printf(" %p", (void*)s->children[i]);
        printf(" }");
    }
    printf(";\n");
}

int main() {
    struct dag *a = new_dag(0);
    struct dag *b = new_dag(2);

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);
    print_dag("a", a);
    print_dag("b", b);

    set_dag_child(b, 0, a);
    set_dag_child(b, 1, a);

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);
    print_dag("a", a);
    print_dag("b", b);

    free_dag(a);    // removes the reference from a to the first dag

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);
    print_dag("b[0]", b->children[0]);
    print_dag("b", b);

    free_dag(b);    // should remove all references to both dags

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
total_dag_nodes=2                                                                                           a: 0x7f885f600000 [refs:1] { };
b: 0x7f885f600010 [refs:1] { 0x0 0x0 };

total_dag_nodes=2                                                                                           a: 0x7f885f600000 [refs:3] { };
b: 0x7f885f600010 [refs:1] { 0x7f885f600000 0x7f885f600000 };

total_dag_nodes=2                                                                                           b[0]: 0x7f885f600000 [refs:2] { };
b: 0x7f885f600010 [refs:1] { 0x7f885f600000 0x7f885f600000 };

total_dag_nodes=0
```

Here is an alternative using a global list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int total_dag_nodes = 0;  // for debugging
static struct dag *dag_list;

struct dag {
    struct dag *next;       // linked list for maintenance
    int n_children;         // Number of children
    struct dag **children;  // Array of pointers to DAGs
};

struct dag *new_dag(int n) {
    struct dag *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;
    total_dag_nodes++;
    s->next = dag_list;
    dag_list = s;
    s->n_children = 0;
    s->children = NULL;
    if (n > 0) {
        s->n_children = n;
        s->children = calloc(sizeof(*s->children), n);
    }
    return s;
}

void free_dag(struct dag *s) {
    /* nothing to do because tag could be referenced elsewhere */
}

void free_all_dags(void) {
    struct dag *p;
    while ((p = dag_list) != NULL) {
        dag_list = p->next;
        free(p->children);
        free(p);
        total_dag_nodes--;
    }
}

void print_dag(const char *name, struct dag *s) {
    printf("%s: %p", name, (void*)s);
    if (s) {
        printf(" {");
        for (int i = 0; i < s->n_children; i++)
            printf(" %p", (void*)s->children[i]);
        printf(" }");
    }
    printf(";\n");
}

int main() {
    struct dag *a = new_dag(0);
    struct dag *b = new_dag(2);

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);
    print_dag("a", a);
    print_dag("b", b);

    b->children[0] = a;
    b->children[1] = a;

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);
    print_dag("a", a);
    print_dag("b", b);

    free_dag(a);  // individual frees do nothing

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);
    print_dag("b[0]", b->children[0]);
    print_dag("b", b);

    free_all_dags();

    printf("\ntotal_dag_nodes=%d\n", total_dag_nodes);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
total_dag_nodes=2                                                                                           a: 0x7f8d7b402650 { };
b: 0x7f8d7b402670 { 0x0 0x0 };

total_dag_nodes=2                                                                                           a: 0x7f8d7b402650 { };
b: 0x7f8d7b402670 { 0x7f8d7b402650 0x7f8d7b402650 };

total_dag_nodes=2                                                                                           b[0]: 0x7f8d7b402650 { };
b: 0x7f8d7b402670 { 0x7f8d7b402650 0x7f8d7b402650 };

total_dag_nodes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to implement a garbage callection algorithm.  There are two basic choices for this

- reference counting

  basically, just add a reference count to every node and increment/decrement it every time you add/remove a reference.  when the refcount drops to 0, free the node.  This works well only as long as you have no cyclces (which DAGs do not)
- mark/sweep

  you need a way of marking nodes as you visit them (maybe just one bit if you can reliably unmark all nodes, or a 'id of last traversal' value).  Then, to free your DAG, you visit all nodes marking them as you go and adding them to a 'to be freed' list if they were not previously marked (the mark phase).  Then, go through the 'to be freed' list freeing them (the sweep phase)